# how to set path for crontab in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, linux-device-driver

When I am  trying to execute python on crontab ,I jut run a dummy program and I found the following information

```
root@beaglebone:/tmp# cat env.output 
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/root
```

I have given my crontab like this

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin

24 20 09 11 * python3 /bin/remote_iomodified.py
```

What will be the path for my corntab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use absolute paths when adding cronjobs:

```
24 20 09 11 * /usr/bin/python3 /bin/remote_iomodified.py
```

Comment: I tried but it is not executing I put source file in /bin and its original location is /home/debian/Desktop/XBee_python/remote_iomodified.py

Comment: try to use its original location then: `24 20 09 11 * /usr/bin/python3  /home/debian/Desktop/XBee_python/remote_iomodified.py`

Comment: I used as follows because my pathon3 path is on /usr/local/bin/python3 50 20 09 11 * /usr/local/bin/python3 /home/debian/Desktop/XBee_python/remote_iomodified.py

Comment: yes one time I want to execute continuously so I put & at the end

Comment: to run always I use like this * * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 /home/debian/Desktop/XBee_python/remote_iomodified.py &

Comment: that will execute your script every minute

Comment: for every second what I have to do

Comment: you can't do that directly with a crontab, you should call another script that calls your script every second or modify your first script to do that

Comment: Or is there is any other way to execute my program in every second

Comment: i would use the [python builtin event scheduler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html)

Comment: So with crontab I have to call python pgm , then python pgm having event scheduler is right

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for the location of a crontab file than it's under

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/username
```

But you really shouldn't edit them directly

Comment: I can not able to execute my program I want to give  my path my original file is located at /home/debian/Desktop/XBee_python/remote_iomodified.py